# Average distance between points in circles

Tags: probability, trigonometry, circles, expected-value

Suppose we have a unit circle with center $p_0$ (let's call that circle $C_0$, this is the red circle). In addition, we have another unit circle with center $p_1$ (let's call that circle $C_1$, this is the blue circle). The distance between the two centers is $d$.

I wonder, how can I calculate the average distance from $p_0$ to the points $p$ s.t $p \in C_1 \text{ and } p \notin C_0$.

Without loss of generality, I'm trying to calculate the average distance between the origin and the points in the yellow area.
[image: illustration]

Currently, I tried to use the Law of cosines with Conditional expectation. But I don't get any insights about the problem in this way.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is the center $p_1$ moving?

Comment: Bring all the thing into polar coordinates, make equation for the blue circle ($x^2+y^2-2xd+d^2=1$ becomes $\rho^2-2d\rho\cos\theta+d^2=1$), find intersections and compute $\dfrac{\iint_D \rho\, \mathrm{d}S}{\iint_D \, \mathrm{d}S}$ where $D$ is the yellow area.

Comment: @SamulGonjo - the centers are given and the distance is constant $d$. Then $p_1$ is static.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thanks for your comment. I did not understand where you use the polar coordinates and what you do with the points of intersection. Can you explain a little more in detail?